# Java Number format how to change +/- sign to custom text

Tags: java, numberformatter

I would like to use number formatting for adding a text different when number is positive or negative

ex :

> -3.5 => (down) 3.5
>
> +3.5 => (up)   3.5

I have found things in DecimalFormatSymbols, but it's only possible to change minus sign and only for a single char

Is there any other simple way using number formater?

```
DecimalFormatSymbols unusualSymbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols(currentLocale);
unusualSymbols.setDecimalSeparator('|');
unusualSymbols.setGroupingSeparator('^');
unusualSymbols.setMinusSign();
String strange = "#,##0.###";
DecimalFormat weirdFormatter =
        new DecimalFormat(strange, unusualSymbols);
weirdFormatter.setGroupingSize(4);

String bizarre = weirdFormatter.format(12345.678);
System.out.println(bizarre);
```

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. What do you mean by "adding a text"?

Comment: How about simply using `(up) #,##0.###;(down) #,##0.###` as your format string? *(from [the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html))*

Comment: @MTCoster You should write that as the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this in your format string for [`DecimalFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html):

```
(up) #,##0.###;(down) #,##0.###
```

The linked doc contains a complete syntax definition for the format string, which starts:

> ```
> Pattern:
>          PositivePattern
>          PositivePattern ; NegativePattern
> ```

This indicates that an optional second format string separated by a semicolon (`;`) will be used for negative values.

Reading further:

> ```
> PositivePattern:
>         Prefix_opt Number Suffix_opt
> NegativePattern:
>         Prefix_opt Number Suffix_opt
> Prefix:
>         any Unicode characters except \uFFFE, \uFFFF, and special characters
> Suffix:
>         any Unicode characters except \uFFFE, \uFFFF, and special characters
> ```

Each pattern (positive and negative) consists of a number format string (`Number`) with an optional prefix and suffix string. These additional parts can be any string you like (including `(up)` and `(down)`).

Answer (score 3):

Set the positive prefix and negative prefix of the [`DecimalFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html):

```
DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat();
formatter.setPositivePrefix("(up) ");
formatter.setNegativePrefix("(down) ");
System.out.println(formatter.format(-3.5));
System.out.println(formatter.format(3.5));
```

Output:

```
(down) 3.5
(up) 3.5
```